# How to pass Eval () to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, eval

This is probably really simple for someone who's familiar with Javascript, but I have having trouble calling a function while passing an eval as a parameter. I've got a bunch of dynamic checkboxes that I'm trying to create. I've got the text displaying great, but the checkbox is giving me trouble. The problem is, the value that I'm passing to the checkbox is a string (either "true" or "false") not a bool.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked='<%# Eval("Value") %>' Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
```

I also created a short javascript function to convert it to boolean

```
function ConvertToBoolean(value)
{
     if (value == "true")
     {    return true;}
     if (value == "false")
     {    return false;}
 }
```

I'm not great with javascript, but I've tried everything I could find on SO. Not sure why it's not working for me. Here's what I've tried:

```
Checked='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
Checked="'<%# Eval("Value") %>'"
Checked='<%# "ConvertToBoolean(" + Eval("Value") + ");" %>'
Checked='<%# "ConvertToBoolean(\"" + Eval("Value") + "\");" %>'
Checked='<%# Eval("Value", "javascript:ConvertToBoolean({0});") %>'
Checked="ConvertToBoolean('<%# Eval("Value") %>')"
```

Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here? Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: what is `"Value"`? a C# variable? also `ConvertToBoolean` could be just `return (value=="true");`

Comment: I fail to see the point on using `Eval`

Comment: @JohnKiller - yes, sorry I should have specified: it is a C# variable, it's from a list of objects (that include other properties like "DisplayName") that is bound to a DataList. (There are other items that are bound as well, aside from the checkbox, let me know if that is pertinent, I can add that code as well). The problem is, the object I'm binding has a string for the "value" instead of bool.

Comment: @JohnKiller - then is my syntax incorrect? With the code above (for the asp:checkbox) I'm getting "cannot convert string to a bool" error

Comment: @JohnKiller, I'm getting the following error: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= (Value=="true") %>' for the 'Checked' property. I tried sticking "Eval" in there, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @JohnKiller - I got it to work! I just needed

Comment: oops - I just needed  Checked='<%# Eval("Value")=="true"%>' to make it work. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. If you will post your comments as an I answer I can select it as answered!

Comment: If you happen to know, I'd appreciate any kind of explanation as to why it would only work on the server side and not with the javascript side like I originally was trying to do. I'd just like to understand javascript better. Thanks again!

Comment: I came from the PHP world and I know little of ASP.NET, sorry. But `<asp>` tags are server side, so it's normal that they are interpreted server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked='<%# Eval("Value")=="true" %>' Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' />
```

This code gets executed at server side and is translated to HTML, something like

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> .....
```

Ofcourse ASP needs to evaluate your `Eval("Value")=="true"` to decide if it needs to output `checked` or not